# ArcGIS Overwrite hosted Feature Service- Allow_Exporting issue

Tags: arcgis-online, export, feature-service

I have a hosted feature service that I overwrite on a nightly basis, this all works fine however I am having issues setting the parameter for "allow_exporting"

I set the value to **`True`** however after the update when I go into ArcGIS Online under item details the box is unchecked for allowing others to export.

I even set the parameter as **`allow_exporting = True`**  but it still does not work. anyone see an issue?

```
arcpy.mp.CreateWebLayerSDDraft(mp, sddraft, sd_fs_name, 'MY_HOSTED_SERVICES', 'FEATURE_ACCESS',"my folder name", True, True, True, allow_exporting=True)
```

and also

```
arcpy.mp.CreateWebLayerSDDraft(mp, sddraft, sd_fs_name, 'MY_HOSTED_SERVICES', 'FEATURE_ACCESS',"my folder name", True, True, True, True)
```

both with the same results.... the document for this function is **[HERE](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/createweblayersddraft.htm)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered a BUG in ArcGIS Python API.
This issue is now classified as:

- `**BUG-000116407 [Hosted Feature Service Settings (Export, Sync, and Edit) always set to False (unchecked) when overwriting a service using the CreateWebLayerSDDraft function in the ArcGIS API for Python].**`

There is no workaround for this issue that I have discovered, other than manually enabling these options in ArcGIS Online.

Answer (score 0):

There's an undocumented 'Extract' option in the [Service Capabilities](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/sync-enabled-feature-services.htm) which can be changed via the ArcGIS API for Python after you've carried out the republish.

```
syncLayers = []
# Dictionary without a key for 'capabilities' which will be added later
sync_update_dict = {'supportsDisconnectedEditing':'False', 'syncEnabled':'False',
               'allowGeometryUpdates': 'False', 'hasStaticData': 'False'}

# Search for and return the first Feature Layer Collection item based on relevance sorting
featureLayer = gis.content.search(query=featureLayerName + " owner:xyz", item_type='Feature Layer Collection', sort_field='relevance', sort_order='desc', max_items=1)
# Get the first result and create a Feature Layer Collection from it
featureLayerColl = FeatureLayerCollection.fromitem(featureLayer[0])
print(featureLayerColl.url)
syncLayers.append(featureLayerColl)

# Add capabilities key to dictionary. Access Tracks layer needs the extra 'Extract' option
# enabled for exporting the data in multiple formats
if featureLayerName == "AccessTracks":
    sync_update_dict["capabilities"] = "Query, Sync, Extract"
    sync_update_dict["syncEnabled"] = "True"

print(sync_update_dict)

for url in syncLayers:
    url.manager.update_definition(sync_update_dict) # comment out if not wanting to update
    url.properties.capabilities
```